# Using __getstate__/__setstate__ with pickle fails with "ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)"

Tags: python, pygame, pickle, getstate

I am attempting to pickle the `pygame.Surface` object, which is not pickleable by default. What I've done is to add the classic picklability functions to the class and overwrite it. This way it will work with the rest of my code.

```
class TemporarySurface(pygame.Surface):
    def __getstate__(self):
        print '__getstate__ executed'
        return (pygame.image.tostring(self,IMAGE_TO_STRING_FORMAT),self.get_size())

    def __setstate__(self,state):
        print '__setstate__ executed'
        tempsurf = pygame.image.frombuffer(state[0],state[1],IMAGE_TO_STRING_FORMAT)
        pygame.Surface.__init__(self,tempsurf)

pygame.Surface = TemporarySurface
```

Here is an example of my traceback when I try to pickle a few recursive objects:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "dibujar.py", line 981, in save_project
    pickler.dump((key,value))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 224, in dump
    self.save(obj)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 286, in save
    f(self, obj) # Call unbound method with explicit self
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 562, in save_tuple
    save(element)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 306, in save
    rv = reduce(self.proto)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py", line 71, in _reduce_ex
    state = base(self)
ValueError: size needs to be (int width, int height)
```

The part that puzzles me is that the print statement is not being executed. Is `__getstate__` even being called? I'm confused here, and I'm not exactly sure what information to put up. Let me know if anything additional would help.

Comment: It might not be called, depending on how different pieces of code import `Surface`.  How is `Surface` used?  Is it possible for you to use your subclass instead of monkeypatching `Surface` itself?

Comment: Well, I'm using other peoples code which passes around Surface objects, so it would be much more difficult for me to use the subclass. Surface is being used as normally and I only run into this error when attempting to pickle it.

Comment: I found this: http://www.mail-archive.com/pygame-users@seul.org/msg13420.html However, are you able to retrieve the filepath or id, and save that instead of the actual pixels?

Answer (score 3):

As [the documentation says](http://docs.python.org/2/library/pickle#pickling-and-unpickling-extension-types), the primary entry point for pickling extension types is the `__reduce__` or `__reduce_ex__` methods.  Given the error, it seems that the default `__reduce__` implementation is not compatible with `pygame.Surface`'s constructor.

So you'd be better off providing a `__reduce__` method for `Surface`, or registering one externally via the `copy_reg` module.  I would suggest the latter, since it doesn't involve monkey patching.  You probably want something like:

```
import copy_reg

def pickle_surface(surface):
    return construct_surface, (pygame.image.tostring(surface, IMAGE_TO_STRING_FORMAT), surface.get_size())

def construct_surface(data, size):
    return pygame.image.frombuffer(data, size, IMAGE_TO_STRING_FORMAT)

construct_surface.__safe_for_unpickling__ = True
copy_reg.pickle(pygame.Surface, pickle_surface)
```

That should be all you need.  Make sure that the `construct_surface` function is available at the top level of a module though: the unpickling process needs to be able to locate the function in order to perform the unpickling process (which might be happening in a different interpreter instance).